# Java class with 2 generic parameters

Tags: java

I'm trying to crate my own thread safe event handling but I get `E cannot be resolved to a type` error on class decleration line below. How can I fix this?

**Observers.java**

```
public final class Observers<T extends EventHandler<E>> {

    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<T> mListeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<T>();

    public interface EventHandler<E> {
       public void HandleEvent(Object sender, E e);
    }

    /*...*/

    public void dispatchEvent(Object sender, E args) {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

**EventHandler.java**

```
public interface EventHandler<E extends EventArgs> {
 /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've only *actually* declared a single type parameter in `Observers`. Try this:

```
public final class Observers<E extends EventArgs, T extends EventHandler<E>> {
```

Note that it looks *highly* odd for your `Observers` class to declare its own nested `EventHandler` interface while implementing the outer one - if you *really* need both of those, I would suggest you rename one of them.