# Simplifying Java class with 2 generic parameters

Tags: java, generics

I try to create this class:

```
public class Class1<T extends Class2<E>> {
    ...
    public E someFunction(T param) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I saw topic [blog]: [Java class with 2 generic parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727117/java-class-with-2-generic-parameters) and in it topic suggest using this solution:

```
public class Class1<T extends Class2<E extends Class3>, E extends Class3> {
    ...
    public E someFunction(T param) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

It is works, but in this case I should using 2 parameters without one:

```
Class1<Class21<Class31>, Class31> var = ...
```

In this solution I duplicate class 'Class31'. Has this task have more simple solution, to using following code:

```
Class1<Class21<Class31>> var = ...
```

**Update1:**

> What problem are you trying to solve?

For example, I have class for images. 
Images can be single-channel (gray image) and multi-channel (3 channels for RGB, HSB and etc. or 4 channels or RGB and etc. + Alpha channel). 
Also, image can save value RGB in byte 0..255 or in float (0.0, 1.0) and it is different type of images.
So, I want to create class for this images and construct it as:

```
MyImage<MyChannelType3<MyColorTypeInt>>   img1 = ...
MyImage<MyChannelType3<MyColorTypeFloat>> img2 = ...
MyImage<MyChannelType1<MyColorTypeFloat>> img3 = ...
```

and have access to colors in pixel as:

```
int Red     = img1.getPixel(x, y)[0];
float Green = img2.getPixel(x, y)[0];
float Gray  = img3.getPixel(x, y);
```

I think is more useful than:

```
MyImage<MyChannelType3<MyColorTypeInt>>   img1 = ...
int Red = img1.getPixel(x, y).getChannel(0).getValue();
```

If I will be firs return *MyChannelType3*, than *MyColorTypeInt* and then *value* or return *Object* and demand casting it to *int*, *float*, *int[]* or *float[]*.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually asking.  What problem are you trying to solve?  I think that your declaration should be `Class1<Class21,Class31> var`, if you're using the form suggested in the blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This redundancy is unavoidable in Java.

Explanation: In Java a *type* parameter is just what the name implies, a formal parameter for a *type* to be substituted with an actual *type*. What you require is more. You need `T` to be a parameter for a *type constructor*. Much like a classes' constructor produces instances of the class, a type constructor produces types. `List` is a type constuctor which given the actual type `String` produces the type `List<String>`.

Applying this knowledge to your problem, you would want `T` to be a type constructor which takes types `E <: Class3` producing types `T <: Class2<E>` where `<:` is the subtype relation. This might be declared and used as follows.

```
class Class1<T<X extends Class3> extends Class2<X>, E extends Class3> {
    public E someFunction(T<E> param) {
        ...
    }
}

Class1<Class21, Class31> var = ...
```

Further reading on the subject can be found in [Generics of a Higher Kind](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2579) ([pdf](http://adriaanm.github.com/files/higher.pdf)). Beyond that you can have a look at [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) which offers higher kinds.

**Edit based on update**: A perhaps preferable solution might be to implement a `PixelAccessor`.

```
public class PixelAccessor<C extends YourColor> {
    public static <C extends YourColor> get(Image<? extends ChannelType<? extends C>> image) {
        return new PixelAccessor<C>(image);
    }

    private final Image<? extends ChannelType<? extends C>> image;

    private PixelAccessor(Image<? extends ChannelType<? extends C>> image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public C getPixel(int x, int y) {
        // sadly this is unchecked, but "weak" type systems demand compromises
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        C color = (C) image.getPixel(x, y);
        return color;
    }
}
```